# Always on top with jQuery

Tags: jquery, offset

I try to get a button that stays always on top of the page even when there is an scroll.Can anyone help?

(This is a simplified case. I cannot use position fixed)

You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/TCX6h/6/

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    var boto = $('.boto').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (boto < 0) {
            $( '.boto' ).offset({ top: 50 });
        } 
    });
})
```

Comment: in your fiddle, you use `$('#boto')` but have only `<div class="boto"></div>`. One of those needs to change if you want anything to happen. (although there are other things wrong too, as noted in my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of why your (original, unedited) code doesn't work,

1. `boto` doesn't point back to `$('#boto').offset().top`, it merely stores it's value.
2. `==` isn't an assignment, it's a logical comparison (so `boto == 0` isn't giving `boto` a value of `0`, it's just comparing it to `0` and returning `true`/`false`).
3. that's not how you use `.offset()` to set position: 
   http://api.jquery.com/offset/
4. `.offset()` works relative to the document, not relative to the viewport

Try:

```
$(function(){
    var boto = $('#boto');
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        boto.offset({top: document.body.scrollTop});
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/TCX6h/7/

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of jquery use css `position:fixed`

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCX6h/2/)

Or you can do it this way:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll( function() {
        var boto =$(window).scrollTop() - $('.boto').offset().top;
        if (boto)
            $('.boto').addClass('top');
        else
            $('.boto').removeClass('top');
    } );
})
```

css:

```
.boto.top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCX6h/8/)

Comment: Sure, but I just simplified the case here to show the problem. But I cannot do that. (I have others divs on top... everything is quite complex)

Answer (score 0):

yes @ RAM is right .check this

```
#background {
position:fixed;
top:0;
    ...
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCX6h/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Give your button fixed position instead of absolute

```
    .boto{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0px; left:50%;
    margin-left:-115px;
    width:30px; height:20px;
    cursor:pointer;

    background:yellow;
    padding:30px 100px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCX6h/4/)